# Is it possible to get Android accelerometer values inside onCreate method?

Tags: android, initialization, accelerometer, android-sensors, oncreate

Is it possible to get Android accelerometer values inside `onCreate` method? I want it,
so as to make some initializations after reading them. So far, I have registered
a sensor listener to get those values when they change through the [onSensorChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorListener.html#onSensorChanged%28int,%20float%5B%5D%29)
callback. I have 3 float attributes (*lastx*, *lasty* and *lastz*) initialized to -1, so as to store the accelerometer values there upon change. In `onCreate` method, after registering my sensor listener, I am trying to check these values, but they are always equal to -1. Is there a way to get these values inside the `onCreate` method?

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
    private SensorManager sensorManager;

    TextView textView;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    float lastx = -1;
    float lasty = -1;
    float lastz = -1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        textView = new TextView(this);

        SensorManager manager = (SensorManager) 
                     getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

        Sensor accelerometer = manager.getDefaultSensor(
                                     Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

        if(!manager.registerListener(this, accelerometer,
                                     SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME)){
        Log.d("ERROR: ", "NO accelerometer found!");
        }

        setContentView(textView);
        builder.setLength(0);

        builder.append(
           "X " + this.lastx + "\nY " + this.lasty + "\nZ " + this.lasty);
        textView.setText(builder.toString());

         Log.d(" * accelerometer values:",
            "X: " + this.lastx+", Y: " + this.lasty + ", Z: " + this.lastz);

    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor,int accuracy){

    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){

            // check sensor type
            if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){

                 // assign directions
                 float x=event.values[0];
                 float y=event.values[1];
                 float z=event.values[2];

                 this.lastx = x;
                 this.lasty = y;
                 this.lastz = z;

                 // builder.setLength(0);
                 // builder.append("X " + x + "\nY " + y + "\nZ " + z);
                 // textView.setText(builder.toString());
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: "I want it, so as to make some initializations after reading them" -- put your initializations in `onSensorChanged()`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the main user interface thread is used for both the `onCreate` and the `onSensorChanged`.   So `onSensorChanged` can't run until `onCreate` has finished.  Whatever initialisation you need to do, I suggest you arrange for it to be done on the first call to `onSensorChanged`, e.g. by doing the initialisation if the values are -1.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have already thought about this solution and I 'm sure it works. But I am curious if it is possible to get these values from inside the `onCreate` function, even in some other, maybe a hacky way.

Comment: Any such method wouldn't be via `onSensorChanged` for the threading reason that I mentioned.  If there is such a method, then I'm not aware of it.  Also, if the phone is moving around even slightly (which is quite likely if someone has just launched your app because they'll be holding the device), then the accelerometer values you'll see are highly volatile.  So I'm finding it hard to imagine what useful initialization you want to do on the basis of what will look like almost random input.

Comment: Ok, yes you have absolutely right. I will wait for little more.. If there is no other answer, I will mark yours as the correct one. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Initialize some variables first.

```
int value , count = 0 , newVal;
```

Inside onSensorChanged

```
if(count == 0){

            value = (int) event.values[0];

            count++;

        }

        newVal = (int) event.values[0] - value ;
```